# Error al leer propiedad de undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Cuando intento hacer

```
ng build --prod
```

Muestra el siguiente error:

> 92% chunk asset optimizationC:\Users\IvanTadeo\Documents\petstar\front-end\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\input-source-map-tracker.js:37  if (originalPosition.line === null && line > 1 && selectorFallbacks > 0) {
>                          ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined

¿Por qué sale ese error? ¿Cómo puedo poner angular en producción?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
npm install clean-css@4.1.11
npm uninstall clean-css
npm ls clean-css
```

y vuelve a compilar.